# Audio Balancing Issue

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am new to Ubuntu. My ubuntu version is 18.04. I've been facing some very low volume issues in ubuntu. While trying to fix it using AlsaMixer **I mistakenly increase my left speaker volume.I dont know how many times I pressed the Q button.** Now I am unable to balance it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Pulse Audio Volume Control:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/advanced-audio-control-on-linux/

It has a include left/right channel setting and may allow you to fix what happened.